# How to integrate Files with dejadup

Tags: pantheon-files, backup

The official backup tool in Debian systems is dejadup. It has integration with Nautlus in Gnome. Is there any possible way of getting the same support in Files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an approach to integrating deja-dup with Files. I found in the following blogpost from Todd Kennedy.

[Source](http://todd1215.blogspot.com.au/2014/02/adding-deja-dup-support-to-pantheon.html)

## Adding Deja-dup support to Files

Obviously, install deja-dup. In order to integrate Deja-Dup into Files one has to create two files; the first for restoring missing files from a directory and the second to revert to a previous version of a file.

The dejadup-restore.contract, that must be created in /usr/share/contractor with Admin permissions.

```
[Contractor Entry]  
Name=Restore missing files in folder  
Icon=edit-find  
Description=Restores missing files in folder using dejadup  
MimeType=inode/directory  
Exec=deja-dup --restore-missing %U  
Gettext-Domain=deja-dup
```

Save and exit editing

The  dejadup-revert.contract in the same way that you created the first file. Put the following contents into it.

```
[Contractor Entry]  
Name=Revert to previous version...  
Description=Revert to a previous version  
Icon=edit-find  
MimeType=application/octet-stream  
Exec=deja-dup --restore %U  
Gettext-Domain=deja-dup
```

Save and exit editing.

Log-off and log-on.